# JFormattedTextField destroys DocumentFilter

Tags: java, swing, formatting, jformattedtextfield, documentfilter

I have a Problem with the JFormattedTextField (I use it as a base class for all of our text fields).

Today I tried to add a document filter to the document of this field which works just fine, but only as long it doesnt have a formatter factory set.

The Problem is, when the formatter factory is set (in my case the default classes) and processFocusEvent is called following happens (JFormattedTextField.java:595):

```
    // if there is a composed text, process it first
    if ((ic != null) && composedTextExists) {
    ic.endComposition();
    EventQueue.invokeLater(focusLostHandler);
    } else {
    focusLostHandler.run();
    }
    }
    else if (!isEdited()) {
        // reformat
        setValue(getValue(), true, true);
    }
```

then setValue() is called (JFormattedTextField.java:757):

```
private void setValue(Object value, boolean createFormat, boolean firePC) {
    Object oldValue = this.value;

    this.value = value;

    if (createFormat) {
        AbstractFormatterFactory factory = getFormatterFactory();
        AbstractFormatter atf;

        if (factory != null) {
            atf = factory.getFormatter(this);
        }
        else {
            atf = null;
        }
        setFormatter(atf);
    }
    else {
        // Assumed to be valid
        setEditValid(true);
    }

    setEdited(false);

if (firePC) {
    firePropertyChange("value", oldValue, value);
}
}
```

As you can see if there is a factory it will try to "refresh" the formatter

(JFormattedTextField.java:439):

```
protected void setFormatter(AbstractFormatter format) {
    AbstractFormatter oldFormat = this.format;

    if (oldFormat != null) {
        oldFormat.uninstall();
    }
    setEditValid(true);
    this.format = format;
    if (format != null) {
        format.install(this);
    }
    setEdited(false);
    firePropertyChange("textFormatter", oldFormat, format);
}
```

And here is the real Problem I have (JFormattedTextField$AbstractFormatter.class:950):

```
    public void uninstall() {
        if (this.ftf != null) {
            installDocumentFilter(null);
            this.ftf.setNavigationFilter(null);
            this.ftf.setFormatterActions(null);
        }
    }
```

Here it destroys my document filter, I know that the formatter holds the documentFilter normally, but was it really intended to work that way?
The document should be the object handling its filter (imho) not the formatter.
Is there a way to go around it without the use of a specialized formatter subclass?

**EXAMPLE CODE:**
(as requested :) )

```
package jftf;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatter;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

/**
 * @author Pawel Miler
 */
public class JFormattedTextFieldExample {

private Container container;
private JFormattedTextField workingTextField;
private JFormattedTextField brokenTextField;
private DocumentFilter documentFilter;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new JFormattedTextFieldExample();
}

public JFormattedTextFieldExample() {
    initializeDocumentFilter();
    initializeTextFields();
    initializeGui();
}

private void initializeDocumentFilter(){
    documentFilter = new UppercaseDocumentFilter();
}

private void initializeTextFields() {
    workingTextField = createTextField(false);
    addDocumentFilter(workingTextField);

    brokenTextField = createTextField(true);
    addDocumentFilter(workingTextField);
}

private JFormattedTextField createTextField(boolean createFormatter) {
    JFormattedTextField textField;
    textField = createFormatter ? new JFormattedTextField(new DefaultFormatter()) : new JFormattedTextField();
    return textField;
}

private void addDocumentFilter(JTextField textField) {
    ((AbstractDocument) textField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(documentFilter);
}

private void initializeGui() {
    container = createFrame();

    container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    Dimension dimension = new Dimension(80, 20);

    brokenTextField.setPreferredSize(dimension);
    container.add(brokenTextField);

    workingTextField.setPreferredSize(dimension);
    container.add(workingTextField);
}

private Container createFrame() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFormattedTextField example");
    frame.setSize(200, 70);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    return frame.getContentPane();
}

public class UppercaseDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

    public void insertString(FilterBypass filterBypass, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        super.insertString(filterBypass, offset, text.toUpperCase(), attr);
    }

    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass filterBypass, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
        super.replace(filterBypass, offset, length, text.toUpperCase(), attrs);
    }
}
}
```

Both text fields should have the same document filter, but type in one and it always will get capital letters the other one does not.

**Current Solution**:
(the workaround I wrote moments ago implemented in a subclass of JFormattedTextField, I need tu use the flag in the case the formatter has a documentfilter too, you can't use both at the same time, but I'm not really happy needing one at all)

```
public boolean isPreserveDocumentFilter() {
    return preserveDocumentFilter;
}

public void setPreserveDocumentFilter(boolean preserveDocumentFilter) {
    this.preserveDocumentFilter = preserveDocumentFilter;
}

/**
 * We need to override if we want to use a documentFilter with DefaultFormatter implementation.
 * For more info see: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074778/jformattedtextfield-destroys-documentfilter">info</a>
 */
@Override
protected void setFormatter(AbstractFormatter format) {
    Document doc = this.getDocument();
    DocumentFilter filter = null;

    if (preserveDocumentFilter) {
        if ( doc instanceof AbstractDocument ) {
            filter = ((AbstractDocument) doc).getDocumentFilter();
        }
    }

    super.setFormatter(format);

    if ( filter != null ) {
        ((AbstractDocument) doc).setDocumentFilter(filter);
    }
}
```

Comment: please from code, code in SSCCE form, short, runnable, compilable just about JFrame with one JFormattedTextField and your DocumentFilter

Comment: please (there isn't specified the formatter, inputmask, verifier then only my shots to the dark) why is there DocumentFilter, whats reason for that, e.g. you can to use NavigationFilter instead of DocumentFilter, but coint has always two sides, there is real requirement to use DocumentFilter for JSpinner with NumberFormatter for NumberSpinnerModel,  otherwise you are able to input any char to the Editor,

Comment: SSCCE wokrs me correctly (including special chars and localized keyboard) for CP1250 on Win8/ Java7,  question how you override custom semaphore for subclassed JFormattedTextField, maybe there is ..., but I don't want to guessing somehow, not playing with

Comment: The need to use those classes is given by the environment I work on, I can't really argue on that aspect. As far I've seen it is a popular way (DocFilter) to implement things like the upper case filter in the example and works fine with JTextField, so JFormattedTextField broke it (so to say). btw my Environment is Win7 x86, Sun JDK 1.6_31.

Comment: there aren't changes between latest jdk6 and jdk7, see my testing code for various situations for JTextComponents

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Basically, the right way seems to be: override getDocumentFilter() on the AbstractFormatter itself

> protected DocumentFilter getDocumentFilter()
>
> Subclass and override if you wish to provide a DocumentFilter to
>   restrict what can be input. install will install the returned value
>   onto the JFormattedTextField.

from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter.html